# Prestashop blocknewsletter in Homepage

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

The blocknewsletter is displayed at the footer, but I need it, also, to show at the Home page as a full width block. (I hope this is understandable).

1. I have added to blocknewsletter.php the herebelow code.
2. I have also transplanted the blocknewsletter to DisplayHome.
3. I have also created the blocknewsletter_home.tpl

Here is the code:

```
public function hookHome($params)
{
     return $this->hookDisplayHome($params);
}

public function hookDisplayHome($params)
{
    if (!isset($this->prepared) || !$this->prepared)
         $this->_prepareHook($params);
    $this->prepared = true;
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blocknewsletter_home.tpl');
}
```

I have also altered the following code to include the home hook. And i unistalled the module and installed it again.

```
if (!parent::install() || !Configuration::updateValue('PS_NEWSLETTER_RAND', rand().rand())
|| !$this->registerHook(array('header', 'footer', 'actionCustomerAccountAdd')))
```

to

```
if (!parent::install() || !Configuration::updateValue('PS_NEWSLETTER_RAND', rand().rand())
|| !$this->registerHook(array('home', 'header', 'footer', 'actionCustomerAccountAdd')))
```

The problem is that the blocknewsletter is not displayed at the hookhome but only at hookfooter. What am I missing here or what am I doing wrong? Do you have any suggestions?

P.S. Prestashop version is 1.6.1.11

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try register this hook too: `$this->registerHook("displayHome");`

be sure that the {hook} is in the template, the module is active, try return a simple string for be sure the hook is being displayed.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I tried to do what u suggested. I echoed a string and it was displayed normally, like this  
   
    public function hookDisplayHome($params)
    { echo 'test blocknewsletter';
 }

Comment: I also registered the hook as you said but the newsletter form is not displayed public function hookDisplayHome($params)
 {
  echo 'test blocknewsletter';
  return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blocknewsletter.tpl');
 }

Comment: when u use   return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mytpl.tpl');    the tpl is inside modules/{urModule}/views/templates/hook/_____ ???

Comment: Yes it is there. The same tpl is displayed at footer but not in displayHome hook.

Comment: The last thing.. try put {hook h="displayHome"} in your theme template, maybe in header.tpl or index.tpl, i cant say more without see the full code, sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Totally my bad but i was so frustrated that i wouldnt think of looking for that. That "last thing" was the RIGHT THING to do in the first place. The index.tpl had two hooks. The {$HOOK_HOME_TAB} and the {$HOOK_HOME_TAB_CONTENT} and not the {$HOOK_HOME}. So the right hook that i should have registered the module to was the DisplayHomeTabContent and not the DisplayHome. Thanks. That saved the day.

Comment: I told that in the answer "be sure that the {hook} is in the template". Otherwise im happy to heart all works, have a nice day!